# Google Directions Services: InvalidValueError, being thrown in productions but not on localhost

Tags: google-maps-api-3, map-directions

I am passing long/lat coordinates in an array (coords2) to Googles Direction Services to return points on a map.  When using the development server (localhost) all works great with JSON data for multiple point returned as expected from the request. But when on the production server (https). I am getting the error:
*"InvalidValueError: in property origin: not a string; and not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lng: not a number; and unknown property Lng"*

I was getting the same error on development server until I converted each point to a number using parseFloat.

```
coords2['lat'] = parseFloat(point[0]);
coords2['lng'] = parseFloat(point[1]);
```

This corrected the error on localhost and all was well until the move to production.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the error.

Answer (score 0):

"OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"

Trying to get the code down to where it could be useful to the discussion here was a useful task in itself.  With it stripped down to its basic nothing-can-be-wrong level, and still resulting in the error forced me to look elsewhere.  It didn't occur me that we could have exceeded our request limit, which was creating the error.